# regex delete characters end xml

Tags: regex

I am trying to make a regular expression to eliminate the excess of an xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<node>
<B/>
</node>string1
string2
```

https://regex101.com/r/US1eCQ/1/

But when I put a breakline make a match and should not. I want everything to be fixed after the closing tag of the xml, if there is a line break or a white space not match.

thx!

Comment: please provide example input text and what you want matched in the body of the question

Comment: in this example you provided, what do you want to be matched?

Comment: Why don't you capture the xml in group and then just retain the xml and discard rest?

Answer (score 0):

The raw PCRE regex is this

`(?:[\S\s]*(?&tag)\K)[\S\s]*(?(DEFINE)(?<tag>(?><(?:(?:/?[\w:]+\s*/?)|(?:[\w:]+\s+(?:(?:(?:"[\S\s]*?")|(?:'[\S\s]*?'))|(?:[^>]*?))+\s*/?)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\S\s]*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\])))|(?:--[\S\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\S\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]*?))>)))`

https://regex101.com/r/t9sydw/1

Replace with empty string for cleanup.

Can be adjusted for Java, JS, etc...

*Easy on the eye version:*

```
 (?:
      [\S\s]* (?&tag) 
      \K 
 )
 [\S\s]* 

 (?(DEFINE)

      (?<tag>                       # (1 start)
           (?>
                <
                (?:
                     (?:
                          /? 
                          [\w:]+ 
                          \s* 
                          /? 
                     )
                  |  
                     (?:
                          [\w:]+ 
                          \s+ 
                          (?:
                               (?:
                                    (?: " [\S\s]*? " )
                                 |  (?: ' [\S\s]*? ' )
                               )
                            |  (?: [^>]*? )
                          )+
                          \s* 
                          /? 
                     )
                  |  
                     \?
                     [\S\s]*? 
                     \?
                  |  
                     (?:
                          !
                          (?:
                               (?:
                                    DOCTYPE
                                    [\S\s]*? 
                               )
                            |  (?:
                                    \[CDATA\[
                                    [\S\s]*? 
                                    \]\]
                               )
                          )
                     )
                  |  (?:
                          --
                          [\S\s]*? 
                          --
                     )
                  |  (?:
                          ATTLIST
                          [\S\s]*? 
                     )
                  |  (?:
                          ENTITY
                          [\S\s]*? 
                     )
                  |  (?:
                          ELEMENT
                          [\S\s]*? 
                     )
                )
                >
           )
      )                             # (1 end)
 )
```